# Why don't we get hot pixels when using live view?

Tags: dslr, long-exposure, live-view, hot-pixels

Why don't we get hot pixels while using live view mode, but do get then on a long exposure? I read somewhere that they appear due to the sensor being activated for too much time, but then, live view should also show them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a long exposure charge is allowed to accumulate on the sensor over a period of time, whereas in live view the sensor is discharged for every frame (so thirty times a second or so). Some hot pixels result from slow charge leakage which only occurs during a long exposure, hence you wouldn't expect to see these in live view.

Also liveview subsamples the sensor so you dont see every pixel.

Comment: +1 - Learn something new every day.  Didn't realize LV subsampled.  Upon thinking about it, it would really have to - just didn't realize.

Comment: Question is - does it subsample when viewing 10x zoom in??

Comment: @ysap As far as I know there's always some form of sampling/interpolation going on - you never get a 1:1 correspondence between sensor and LCD pixels. 10x magnification is the same size regardless of how many megapixels you have so there must be some scaling going on!

Comment: Ok, running some numbers, I believe the LCD screen on a 5D is 640 by 480. It's marketed as 920,000 "dots" but they count the red/green/blue subpixels as separate dots, thus 640 x 480 x 3 = 921,600 the sensor resolution is about 5616 x 3744 (give or take some masked pixels) so at 10x magnification you're looking a patch of sensels measuring 562 x 374 so it would be possible to show the sensor pixels 1:1, however given the sharpness, and the existence of cameras with less than 21MP, I think the camera subsamples, then *upsamples* the live view data!

Comment: @MattGrum - That makes sense given what I see when using 10x LV for astro.

Comment: I dunno, I don't see any less detail when zooming in during live view than when I zoom in on the image review.

Comment: it doesnt subsample to 1x liveview and then upsample to 10x. I use mostly manual lenses and 10x liveview is amazing for getting tack sharp eye lashes. If it downsamples and the upampled those details would vanish.